# Chart multiple regions on one histogram

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, chart, histogram

I'm having trouble trying to chart multiple regions onto one histogram.

```
var urban1 = urban.first().geometry();
var pine_forest1 = pine_forest.first().geometry();


var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(urban1, {label: 'urban'}),
  ee.Feature(pine_forest1, {label: 'pine_forest'}),
]);

var hist = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: may_filtered_clip,
  region: regions,
  scale: 20
}).setOptions( {
  series : {
      0 : {color : 'red'},
      1 : {color : 'green'}
    }
  });
  
print(hist);
```

This is the result of the code:
[image: histogram, all red]

And this is basically what I'm aiming for:

[image: Histogram, multiple colors]